# Input string was not in a correct format error using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to insert some data into the database but getting the error mentioned above.  The data type for this field in SQL Server is numeric(4,2). I have tried all kind of solution but cannot get it to work.  here is my code:

```
 TextBox Hours = row.FindControl("Hrs") as TextBox; 

cmd.CommandText = "insert into myTable (ID, HOURS) values (@ID, @HOURS) ";
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID.Text;
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@HOURS", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Hours.ToString());
```

i have also tried to use decimal but not sure how to fix it. thanks

Comment: Calling `ToString()` on a `TextBox` will not give you a useful string

Comment: Why are you adding it as VarChar when it is Numeric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i found the solution.

```
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Hours.Text))
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HOURS", DBNull.Value);
                else
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HOURS", decimal.Parse(Hours.Text));
```

Comment: decimal.Parse will crash your code if the user doesn't type a valid number

Answer (score 2):

You said the type is numeric, but you're trying to add varchar parameters.

Try changing how you're adding parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(ID.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HOURS", Convert.ToInt32(Hours.Text));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass an integer to your parameter, you should convert the Text property of the TextBox, not the instance variable. Calling ToString on the Hours TextBox return `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` and of course this cannot be converted to an integer.

Of course the parameter type should be `SqlDbType.Int` not a VarChar

```
TextBox Hours = row.FindControl("Hrs") as TextBox; 
cmd.CommandText = "insert into myTable (ID, HOURS) values (@ID, @HOURS) ";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@HOURS", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Hours.Text);
```

If the field HOURS expects a decimal value (4,2) then you need to create a decimal type parameter.
Also I suggest to add some check on the input box

```
decimal hourValue;
if(!decimal.TryParse(Hours.Text, out hourValue)    
   // Message to the user that he/she has typed an invalid number
else
{
    TextBox Hours = row.FindControl("Hrs") as TextBox; 
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into myTable (ID, HOURS) values (@ID, @HOURS) ";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@HOURS", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = hourValue;
}
```

Comment: What it the value contained in the Hours TextBox?

Comment: okay the data type in the back end is numeric(4,2) and i am typing like 25 or 45

Comment: i am doing a for loop in the gridview so it does not like when the rest of the rows are null or blank. if i fill out all the rows in the gridview then it works. how can i overcome that?

Comment: It depends. Do you want null values or not? If not then inform the user, if yes (and the database table accepts null values) pass DBNull.Value as value for the parameter

Comment: how do i pass the dbnull value for the parameter?

Comment: @moe use `object Hours = DBNull.Value;`, you can check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
object Hours = DBNull.Value;
Hours = row.FindControl("Hrs") as TextBox;     
cmd.CommandText = "insert into myTable (ID, HOURS) values (@ID, @HOURS) "; 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ID.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@HOURS", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Decimal.Parse((Hours.Text));
```

Comment: i am still getting this error: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @moe On which line do you get that?

Comment: the last line where you say: Decimal.Parse((Hours.Text)

Comment: Debug that line and tell me what value is in Hours.Text

Comment: i am doing a for loop in the gridview so it does not like when the rest of the rows are null.  if i fill out all the rows in the gridview then it works.  how can i overcome that?

Comment: @moe you better post your full code so we can see where you make mistake.